# Skipping an exception in all Python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest, skip

I'm using Python's `unittest` with `pytest` for integration testing a library against a third-party API.

Some of the API calls are temporarily returning an error which raises a specific exception in my code. This behaviour is fine in the code.

However, rather than having the tests fail, I'd rather skip these temporary errors.

I have over 150 tests. Rather than rewriting each and every test like this:

```
class TestMyLibrary(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_some_test(self):
        try:
            // run the test as normal
            // assert the normal behaviour
        except SomeException:
            // skip the test

    def test_some_other_test(self):
        try:
            // run the test as normal
            // assert the normal behaviour
        except SomeException:
            // skip the test
```

Can I rather wrap them all somehow at the class level, or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a decorator. For example:

```
def handle_lastfm_exceptions(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kw)
        except pylast.WSError as e:
            if (str(e) == "Invalid Method - "
                          "No method with that name in this package"):
                msg = "Ignore broken Last.fm API: " + str(e)
                print(msg)
                pytest.skip(msg)
            else:
                raise(e)
    return wrapper
```

And then decorate the problematic functions:

```
class TestMyLibrary(unittest.TestCase):

    @handle_lastfm_exceptions
    def test_some_bad_test(self):
        // run the test as normal
        // assert the normal behaviour

    def test_some_good_test(self):
        // run the test as normal
        // assert the normal behaviour
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect this exception why don't you check its raised when it should? 
You can use :

```
pytest.raises(Exceptiontype, Foo())
```

Comment: It's happening for over 50 tests. It's a temporary error in the third-party API for certain calls, which used to work and they should be fixing soon. In the meantime, I'd rather just globally skip than find and edit each test, then have to review later and revert as each is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem (instable 3rd party library, waiting for fix...). ended up with something like this:

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    from _pytest.runner import pytest_runtest_makereport as orig_pytest_runtest_makereport
    tr = orig_pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)

    if call.excinfo is not None:
        if call.excinfo.type == SomeExceptionFromLibrary:
            tr.outcome = 'skipped'
            tr.wasxfail = "reason: SomeExceptionFromLibrary. shame on them..."

    return tr
```

works like a charm